# How to replace a document in mongo db using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can any one help how to use replaceone function in node.js to replace the whole document in mongodb

Comment: The API for replacing a document using MongoDB & NodeJS is: [replaceOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#replaceOne). This is link to the [MongoDB NodeJS tutorials - CRUD Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/crud/) - look for a section for Update Documents.

Answer (score 0):

As from the name and documentation [replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/index.html) is used to **Replaces a single document within the collection based on the filter**.

The Syntax from the documentation

```
db.collection.replaceOne(
   <filter>,
   <replacement>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     hint: <document|string>                   // Available starting in 4.2.1
   }
)
```

To replace multiple documents,

1) Remove the desired documents with [remove()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) Method and then, run [insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) Method.

**OR**

2) use [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) Method to update multiple documents matching the filter with a particular set of value.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],
     hint:  <document|string>        // Available starting in MongoDB 4.2.1
   }
)
```